# How to read output of SmileBASIC SPCHK?

Tags: basic

I'm trying to get the XY coordinates of a moving sprite in SmileBASIC, and I can't figure it out. I have the single variable returned from SPCHK, but when I print it, I get a single number '4' constantly as the sprite moves. How do I get each bit?

From the documentation:
Return Values   for SPCHK
|b00| XY-coordinates (1), #CHKXY
|b01| Z-coordinates (2), #CHKZ
|b02| UV-coordinates (4), #CHKUV
|b03| Definition number (8), #CHKI
|b04| Rotation (16), #CHKR
|b05| Magnification XY (32), #CHKS
|b06| Display color (64), #CHKC
|b07| Variable (128), #CHKV

For each bit, a target is assigned (If 0 is assigned for all bits, animation is being stopped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SPCHK` only tells you *which* properties are currently being animated, not their values.

To get the actual position, you can use `SPOFS id OUT x,y`

Example:

```
SPSET 0,17
SPANIM 0,"XY",-10,100,100
WAIT 5
SPOFS 0 OUT X,Y
?X,Y 'should be 50,50
```